# Problem with storing images in sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

I am trying to store images in sql server with data type `image` now the problem is getting stored into two rows, i am using FileUpload control to upload image, my code is as follows

```
byte[] imagedata = ImageUpload.FileBytes;
con.Open();
SqlCommand insertImageCmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Images(ImageName,Image) values (@name, @image)", con);
insertImageCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", imageNameTextBox.Text);
insertImageCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", imagedata );
insertImageCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

is this the correct way store images? please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its getting stored as two rows, using the code you've posted, I think that you might somehow be double posting your page.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do:

```
byte[] image = File.ReadAllBytes(path)
```

Then you can insert it in your database.

tip:

When you use a SqlConnection, surround it with the [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) keyword:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{

}
```